# class or method alias in java

Tags: java

I have long java class and method names

```
LONGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGClass.longggggggggggggggggggggggggMethod();
```

I want to alias it to
`g.m();` in another class
can this be done?

Comment: What do you mean by "alias it to g.m()"? Why do you want to copy your looong class to some other class?

Comment: You know, if you learn how to touch type, long class and method names won't bother you so much.

Comment: You know, if you use pretty well any editor other than notepad, long class and method names won't bother you so much.

(LONGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGClass is looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong)

Comment: If you're using an IDE, they almost all map Ctrl+Space to an auto-insert action.

Comment: @Paul: Still, lines with only two method calls that go on over 150 characters are pretty ... unwieldy ;)

Comment: Just one character less than `WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext` ..

Comment: @Paul Tomblim -- may not be a problem typing but by the time you pass a class member as the parameter to a long named method in another class you have 240 plus character lines of code that are a pain to read.

Comment: The fact that you want to alias it means it needs to be shorter. Shorten the name if you can, or wrap it in a method with a shorter name

Answer (score 48):

No.

Wrap it in a method with a name you like better.

Comment: I'll give this a +1, although I would like to note that if you are calling a method often enough to make this worth while, you probably need some refactoring.

Comment: Bill K, if you have to use code with names like that, and you don't like them, it is probably not code you control.

Comment: This is IMO the best answer. I understand other people trying to find work arounds, but some suggest that the original desire by the threadstarter is not valid, and I disagree with these. I find the question to be PERFECTLY fine, and the answer here is also the best, since it is the most sincere answer.

Answer (score 30):

For one thing, you should rarely be typing the class name.  You might have something like this:

```
import DamnLongPackageNameThatIDontLikeTyping;

class MyCoolClass()
{
    DamnLongClassNameThatIDontLikeTyping dlc=new DamnLongClassNameThatIDontLikeTyping();
    dlc.this();
    dlc.that();
    dlc.tOther();
    dlc.damnLongAnnoyingMethodNameStillHasToBeTypedEveryTime();
}
```

Okay, so that's not great, but you shouldn't be typing the entire class name very often, just when you first declare it; and the package import makes it so you don't have to type: `DamnLongPackageNameThatIDontLikeTyping.DamnLongClassNameThatIDontLikeTyping` every time.

Still, that can be annoying to type.  Enter the editor.  If you aren't using Eclipse, Netbeans or IntelliJ then you really need to stop reading right now and go install it--load up your project.  I'll wait....

---

Seriously.  Go get it.  The rest of this won't be any fun without it.

---

Now, the really neat thing is that to get what I typed above, you just do this:

```
class MyCoolClass()
{
    DLC<ctrl-space>
```

After typing that, your file will look like this:

```
import DamnLongPackageNameThatIDontLikeTyping;

class MyCoolClass()
{
    DamnLongClassNameThatIDontLikeTyping<your cursor here>
```

Note that you didn't type damn long ANYTHING, just DLC  It figured out what class you wanted to import, added an import for it and stuck the class in there.  (You may have to choose from a list of classes if there is more than one match).

On top of that, once you have an object named dlc instantiated you can type:

`dlc.<ctrl-space>`  and get a list of methods in that class.  NEVER AGAIN TYPE A METHOD NAME.  If there are a kagillion methods in your class, don't scroll over them, type: `dlc.dLAM<ctrl-space>` to get `dlc.damnLongAnnoyingMethodNameStillHasToBeTypedEveryTime();`

Never type a long method name again.

No long method names, no long class names, no long package names.  Yet you get extremely readable methods, packages and classes.  This is why java programmers tend to use these long names, we also try to remember that we are coding for the next guy and don't want him to have to run all over our code trying to figure out what:

`g.m();` refers to -- forcing them to remember that in this class it means `GreatClass.motion`, but in the next class it means `Grey.modifyColor` -- that would be really cruel.

Java being statically typed places a LOT of power into the editor.  It can do things that you can't even dream of doing with dynamically typed languages, and you should play to the strength of your language to be an effective programmer -- not try to fit each language into some style you learned from using another language.

Note that this works for static methods as well...

`DLC<ctrl-space>.dLM<ctrl-space>`  would be replaced by a call to `DamnLongClass.damnLongMethod()`, and it would even include the parens for you in 9 keystrokes.

Comment: You are right of course. But **readability** is also a quality factor for code. In my case I have a lot of auto-generated classes -- and as it happens for each package there is one `ObjectFactory` for example. When I now use `ObjectFactory` from two packages I need to **fully qualify** them with their package. So I get `com.longCompanyName.longProjectName.carStorageProvider.ObjectFactory` all over the place. How do I long for `import com.longCompanyName.longProjectName.carStorageProvider.ObjectFactory as CarFactory`. (Can't give you the full two examples here, because my comment space ran out)

Comment: @towi I have started to package those classes (with very generic names that are in multiple places) inside another class. I.e. a class CarStorageProvider instead of package. That way you can import CarStorageProvider and then reference ObjectFactory as CarStorageProvider.ObjectFactory. Also 'helps' with ClassBloat (atleast as far as display in the IDE is concerned)

Comment: @towi Stefan is absolutely right, if you are including two ObjectFactories in multiple areas you are certainly breaking the Single Responsibility Principle and probably a few other rules.  By consolidating them into a new class you will find that you always needed that class and will have a place to move a lot more code you had duplicated from other classes (those that imported the two ObjectFactories at least)

Comment: @BillK I will pass that along to our architects ;-) The multiple `ObjectFactories` come from the various Jaxb packages from different providers. I write an interface so the two talk to each other.

Comment: Then that should only effect one file and you will only need to supply the entire path the first time you instantiate the object--shouldn't be too bad.  I have a feeling it goes beyond that though.  If it's a collction of static methods, perhaps you could write an OO wrapper around your "architects" function-based design?  Perhaps there are further issues.  I realize there are constraints that can make things more difficult in ways that are difficult to fully express in a comment :)

Comment: tl;dr - an IDE is helpful.

Answer (score 27):

The Java language provides no aliasing mechanism.

However, you could ease your "pain" somewhat by some combination of the following:

- For static methods, you can use static imports to avoid having the long class name.
- You could declare your own convenience class with a short name and short method names, and implement the static methods to delegate to the real methods like:

  public static void shortName(...) {
  VeryLongClassName.veryLongMethodName(...);
  }
- For regular methods, you could implement a Wrapper class, or a subclass with more convenient method names.  However, both have downsides from the maintenance and (depending on your JVM) performance perspectives.
- In Java 8 and later, you could potentially take a method reference, assign it to a named variable, and use that to make your calls.

But lets step back:

- If the real problem is that you are just fed up with *typing* long names, a solution is to use a modern IDE that supports completion of names as you type them.  See @BillK's answer for example.
- If the real problem is that you are fed up with the long names *taking to much space*, a solution is to use a wider screen / longer lines.  Most monitors are big enough to display 120 character (or more) wide source code with no eye strain.
- If neither of the above is the answer, consider just refactoring the offending code to use sensible (i.e. shorter) class and method names.  Once again, a modern IDE can handle this kind of refactoring quickly and safely.

On the last point, I would consider that the overly long class names and method names are *bad style*.  IMO, you are justified in taking the time to fix them yourself, or suggesting that they be fixed, especially if they constitute a "public" API for some library or module.

---

<sup>To those who would argue that long identifiers are good style because they convey more information, the counter argument is that they don't actually improve readability.  But if you say that they do improve readability, then it follows that using aliases instead of the long identifiers would be *reducing* readability!</sup>

Comment: I disagree that this implies "bad style" per se; and I don't think one should have to use an IDE either. Languages such as ruby allow for aliases and I can tell from experience that it is awesome. So Java not having simple means for aliases, other than e. g. just writing a shorter method name that calls the other method, feels artificially crippling.

Comment: @shevy - I have noted your opinion.  However, this is not a discussion forum.

Comment: I agree with @StephenC, that long names are bad style. Names should be as short and descriptive as possible, especially with a public API.   See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218263/very-long-class-names  and for a little laugh https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-most-ridiculous-Java-class-names-from-real-code. Long story short, no one likes an eyesore, even yourself (you admit), so why put yourself (or someone else) through that?

Answer (score 14):

Actually there *is* a way to get 1/2 of what you're after.

Looking at your example:

```
LONGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGClass.longggggggggggggggggggggggggMethod();
```

It appears that `longggggggggggggggggggggggggMethod` is static.  (If it weren't, you'd be prefixing it with a variable name, which you control the size of.)

You can use [Java's static import feature](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) to 'alias' or *import* the static methods of the `LONGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGClass` into your own class' namespace.  Instead of the above code, you would only have to write this:

```
longggggggggggggggggggggggggMethod();
```

Comment: Note, that this will not be available for pre-Java 6 source

Answer (score 12):

You can use inheritance or encapsulation to wrap the original class.

```
class g extends LONGCLASS 
{ 
   void a() { super.loooonnng(); }
}
```

or

```
class g
{
   private LONGCLASS lc;
   void a() { lc.loooonnng(); }
}
```

Comment: -1 `base` is C#, the OP is talking Java so use `super` and as @erickson said, this is also a static method so this won't work anyway.

Comment: By his use of *Class.method(). In addition, if he was using an object variable, as others have pointed out, using a short variable name would be trivial as he would define that in his own class/methods - the class name however, he cannot change apparently.

Comment: This isn't possible in so many cases. For example, what if you're looking at classes generated by jaxb into which an xml document is being deserialised. It doesn't matter how many times you extend the class -- it'll be totally ignored. It also doesn't really work if you have static methods/fields (which is in the OP's post), or if you have a final class.

Comment: @EngineerDollery: The encapsulation variant should work in the scenarios you mention, should it not?

Answer (score 6):

Not supported in Java.

There is an [enhancement ticket (7166917)](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7166917) for adding **aliases for imports** which would be helpful. The idea is this :

```
import a.very.lng.pckage.* as shortpckg
import my.pckage.IsAVeryLongClassName as MyShort
```

Comment: Yea ... submitted in 2013.  It is now 2022, and there is no sign that it is going to be acted on soon.

Comment: @StephenC that's indeed the status. You can draw your own conclusions. My conclusion? 2 years after posting this answer I started as a Node.js freelancer.

Comment: Well ... my conclusion is that type aliases are a bad idea :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Shorten
{

    public static final Shorten m = new Shorten();

    public int a(params)
    {
        return some_method_with_long_name(params);
    }

    public void b()
    { 
        // whatever static code you want
    }
}
```

In your main code then:

```
import static mypackage.Shorten.m;
...
int res = m.a(params);
m.b();
...
```

This way you effectively alias any static stuff you want, while avoiding warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I only ran a simple test but I defined an inner class variable. I'm not an expert nor do I know the consequences of doing this but I obtained positive results.

```
package a.b;

public class Library {
    public static String str;
}
```

Now write a class to access the static variables from Library

```
package a.b;

public class Access {
   public class Short extends Library {}
   Short.str;
}
```

Comment: 1) This is not defining an alias.  If `str` is 100 characters long you still have to use those 100 characters in `Access`.  2)  A static import of `a.b.Library.*` has the same effect.