# Is it possible to alias data type and values

Tags: java

I'm using BigDecimal a lot and it can be a lot to type.
Is there something I can do like bD = BigDecimal?
Also I am using an object property a lot on a jsf page 
ex. timberSaleController.selected, can I alias that entire value to something like timberSaleController.selected = selected?

Comment: Look at this thread.It is not possible in java. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204157/class-or-method-alias-in-java

Comment: Short answer: no.  Long answer: nooooooo.

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll just deal with the carpal tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything like a type alias that I know of in Java but you could just derive the class.

```
public class bD extends BigDecimal{

    public bD(double val) {
        super(val);
    }

}
```

And use bD.

You'll need to add the constructors you need though.

For the property alias there is nothing like that but if you want to type less, just create a static method that does what you want

```
public class MyClass{
...
    public static void selected(Boolean value){
        thatLongObject.selected = value;
    }
```

and then in any other class you can import the static method

```
import MyClass.selected;
```

and later use it

```
...
// some code
selected(true);
...
```

Comment: Yes, I added the constructor and it builds correctly. Should do what you want.